# jQuery Accordion Gap

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

I'm using the default jQuery Accordion, when I add lots of content in the first panel and very little content in the second panel the second panel height matches the first so there's a big gap.

http://jsfiddle.net/yzm2b959/

```
jQuery(".accordion").accordion( { autoHeight: false } );
```

Does anyone know why this is happening? Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will help you

```
jQuery(".accordion").accordion( {heightStyle: "content"} );
```

[This is result](https://jsbin.com/topigofeye/1)

Answer (score 0):

Use `heightStyle: "content"` instead of `autoHeight: false`:

```
jQuery(".accordion").accordion( { heightStyle: "content" } );
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/upd78581/)